# Check variables through a loop

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I can't seem to figure out how to loop a variable check. What I am trying to do is something like checking those two variables but in a loop

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    $action = $_GET['action'];
}
else{
    $action = NULL;
}

if(isset($check)){
    $check = $check;
}
else{
    $check = NULL;
}
```

I want to do something like this or more effiecient if possible

```
$variables = array($_GET['action'], $check);
$define = array($action, $check);

foreach($variables as $variable){
 if(isset($variable){
   $variable = $define;
 }
}
```

I want it to show no errors while I have error_reporting(E_ALL) open
Could someone help me with this?

Comment: `$define` is an array. You are assigning that array to $variable. Plus  you assign it to `$variable` which is a variable in the scope of the loop.
Further more you are putting the values of $action and $check into an array, not a reference to them. Even if it was a reference overwriting the references would not change the value of the old reference.

Comment: Yea but that was an example I would like to know how it would work :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line will lead to warnings if the variables are not set:

```
$variables = array($_GET['action'], $check);    // here you are possibly using unset variables
```

If you want to write it a bit shorter, you could use the ternary operator but that's about it:

```
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : NULL;
$check = isset($check) ? $check : NULL;
```

I don't think there is any more efficient way to check a combination of normal variables and super globals in one sweep.

Comment: Thank you, I have seen that in scripts of other people earlier so I supose thats the most efficient way.